# Adding Functionality to Grafana WorldMap panel

Tags: influxdb, grafana, world-map

I am using Grafana WorldMap panel and Influxdb as the data source to plot the points of a vehicle.

[image: THIS IS THE MAP IMAGE FROM GRAFANA]

Now, I when I hover over these points, it displays like this `n/a:NaN`

I don't know what is this `n/a : NaN`,
I want that when I hover 
over these points, I should get that how many times this point is stored in the database(or any other info like the tags associated with these points). How can I do that?

[image]

Some data from Influx:

```
time                geohash      host         location         value
1490602036767444479 tekx7nfjs6rt Luv-Inspiron                  100
1490603677196025990 tduw7hf1k3zs Luv-Inspiron                  15
1490603780222510535 ttw58x6qxue9 Luv-Inspiron                  6
1490603911122290125 ttw58x6qxue9 Luv-Inspiron                  6
1490604983924097158 ttqn096mpz59 Luv-Inspiron                  19
1490699614650281185 dr5rsgyct32n Luv-Inspiron Bangalore        19
1490699654166573019 fdf92s8typst Luv-Inspiron Bangalore        19
```

I added location just recently, thats why some are not having that location data.

When I add alias(metrics) in the Metrics tab, then these show different colors according to the values,
Can you please explain why?

Comment: NaN stands for "Not a number". Can you show the data from influxdb? Also add a screenshot of your "metrics" tab

Comment: check it now @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two additional steps:

1. add `alias(metric)` to your `select` query
2. Add `metric` to your `Table Label Field` in the `Worldmap` tab

[image]
[image]

Read more about it in the [readme](https://github.com/grafana/worldmap-panel)

> When I add alias(metrics) in the Metrics tab, then these show
>   different colors according to the values, Can you please explain why?

That's because you defined Thresholds under `Worldmap -> Threshold Options`

Comment: Thank you. But what is this metric and why do we need it? And what if I need some different value in the pop over ?

Comment: "metric" is just an alias for "value". You can name it different but  I think the Threshold Option expects it to be aliased "metric". If you don't care about Thresholds you can name it "test123" or what you like. If you want to a different value you can use something like "SELECT "value" AS "metric", "other_value" AS "other_value" . . .". and use "other_value" in the Table label Field